# getting text from string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
         Apples Bananas Oranges
Me       1      2       3  
Brother  4      4       5
```

I need  a regular expression to get number of apples, bananas and oranges each of us "me and my brother" has.

please help me, I'm totally clueless here.

Comment: Is this homework? Because you should never be doing this IRL.

Comment: Are **Me** and **Brother** hard-coded, or are you looking for a more general solution?

Comment: anything missing from string? like html table markup? tabs?

Comment: this is not a homework thats for sure, the real string values is different from this, but I added that for fun factor. no @dragon there is no markup on this table, its just a chunk of a bigger string

Comment: The only way a regular expression (or any simple parser) is going to work is if your data is in some consistent format .. is it?  Or is creating code to parse only the provided example sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want some code like this:

```
$string = file('input.txt');
$headers = array();
$results = array();
foreach($string as $i => $line) {
    preg_match_all('@(\w+)@', $line, $matches);
    if (!$i) {
        $headers = $matches[0];
    } else {
        $name = array_shift($matches[0]);
        $results[$name] = array_combine($headers, $matches[0]);
    }   
}   
print_r($results);
```

which would result in:

```
Array
(   
    [Me] => Array
        (   
            [Apples] => 1
            [Bananas] => 2
            [Oranges] => 3
        )   

    [Brother] => Array
        (   
            [Apples] => 4
            [Bananas] => 4
            [Oranges] => 5
        )   

)
```

Comment: great, it works if the text was inside of a file, but i cant do that. it has to be a string.

Comment: well, that's a trivial change which I'll leave for you saadlulu ;)

Answer (score 0):

Roughly

```
$regexp = "/([\w]+) +([\d]+) +([\d]+) +([\d]+)/";
$matches = array();
preg_match($regexp, $yourDataSet, $matches);
```

Depending on if you are using 1 long string or a string with newlines you can add \n before the last / in the regexp and make it more precise.